# OpenGL Утечка памяти при рендеринге

Tags: opengl

Я новичок в OpenGL. Есть класс Mesh, в котором есть суб-меши(мешбуферы)
Когда рисую 1 объект, всё в порядке.
Начал проверять программу на утечку памяти. В главном цикле удаляю модель No. 1, загружаю модель No.2, потом в другой итерации наоборот, и так далее.

Вот так загружаю модели

```
int mbc = mesh->getMeshBufferCount();
for( int i = 0; i < mbc; ++i ){
    GLuint id = 0;
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &id );
    this->vertexarrayID.push_back( id );

    glGenBuffers( 1, &id );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id );
    this->vertexBuffer.push_back( id );

    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 
    (( mesh->getMeshBuffer( i )->verticies.size() * 3 ) * sizeof( float )),
       mesh->getMeshBuffer( i )->verticies.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    glGenBuffers( 1, &id );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id );
    this->uvBuffer.push_back( id );

    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 
        (( mesh->getMeshBuffer( i )->tcoords.size() * 2 ) * sizeof( float )),
            mesh->getMeshBuffer( i )->tcoords.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    glGenBuffers( 1, &id );
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id );
    this->normalBuffer.push_back( id );

    glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 
        (( mesh->getMeshBuffer( i )->normals.size() * 3 ) * sizeof( float )),
            mesh->getMeshBuffer( i )->normals.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    glGenBuffers( 1, &id );
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, id );
    this->elementBuffer.push_back( id );

    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->getMeshBuffer( i )->indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), 
    mesh->getMeshBuffer( i )->indices.data() , GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

Когда я задокументировал вызов функции render() утечки нет, значит проблема в отрисовке.

```
int mbcount = mesh->getMeshBufferCount();
for( int i = 0; i < mbcount; ++i ){
    glLoadIdentity();
    glBindVertexArray( this->vertexarrayID[ i ] );

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->vertexBuffer[ i ] );
    glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,(void*)0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->uvBuffer[ i ] );
    glVertexAttribPointer(1,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,(void*)0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->normalBuffer[ i ] );
    glVertexAttribPointer(2,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,(void*)0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->elementBuffer[ i ]);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,mb->indices.size(),GL_UNSIGNED_INT,(void*)0);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
}
```

Непонимаю как сделать правильно. 2 модели, автомобиль и самолёт, в каждой итерации одна удаляется другая создаётся, если включить отрисовку то они рисуются но увеличивается память.

---

Проблема была в удалении VAO. Перед удалением поставил `glBindVertexArray`

```
  glBindVertexArray( this->vertexarrayID[ i ] );
  glDeleteVertexArrays( 1, &vertexarrayID[ i ] );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Непонимаю как сделать правильно. 2 модели, автомобиль и самолёт, в каждой итерации одна удаляется другая создаётся, если включить отрисовку то они рисуются но увеличивается память.

начнём с того, что модели удаляются не по отдельности а все сразу, так как при очистке буферов цвета и глубины `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` всё, что было нарисовано стирается и рендерится заново на следующем кадре.

Во вторых - правильно будет при рендеринге биндить не `vbo`(vertex buffer object)  а `vao`(vertex array object) - тоесть вместо

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->vertexBuffer[ i ] );
glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,(void*)0);
//...
```

нужно будет что-то типо

```
glBindVertexArray(this->vertexarrayID[ i ]);
  glDraw...
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

а биндить `vbo` и настраивать чтение аттрибутов вершин нужно только **один раз** перед рендерингом, при загрузке модели, иначе теряется смысл использования `vao` , который избавляет от дублирующихся операций в цикле отрисовки, другими словами вот этот кусок кода

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->vertexBuffer[ i ] );
glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,(void*)0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->uvBuffer[ i ] );
glVertexAttribPointer(1,2,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,(void*)0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->normalBuffer[ i ] );
glVertexAttribPointer(2,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,(void*)0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->elementBuffer[ i ]);
```

поместите в то место, где у вас загружается модель.

И раз уж заговорили о правильности - не пользуйтесь функциями из устаревшего `opengl API`, я про `glLoadIdentit()` - есть куча математических [библиотек](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/index.html) заточенных под `opengl`.

И наконец, касательно утечки памяти - удаляйте каждый буфер через

```
glDeleteBuffers(1, &this->vertexBuffer[ i ]);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &this->vertexarrayID[ i ]);
```

Comment: В примерах www.opengl-tutorial.org заметил что было убрано `glGenVertexArrays( 1, &id );`  и `glBindVertexArray( this->vertexarrayID[ i ] );` Я убрал эти строки, рисование прекратилось. Как и утечка памяти. Как я понял нужно делать правильный VBO.

Comment: @ArtemRachmaninov вам надо почитать про [vbo](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Buffer_Object) и [vao](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object)